# How to disable link after first click in php

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

i try to disable link after first click but link always enable 
this my code

**

```
$kode = md5(uniqid(rand()));
$to = $_GET['f11'];
            $headers = "From: rizka.nugroho@omg-indonesia.com\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-to: $to\r\n";
            $pesan    = "Klik link berikut untuk verifikasi dan mengaktifkan akun : ";
            $pesan    .= ROOT."active.php?email=".$_GET['f11']."&kode=$kode&username=".$_GET['f5'];

            $a = @mail($to, "Aktivasi Akun Anda", $pesan, $headers);
```

**

and this active.php

```
**$username = $_GET['username'];

    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx") or die(mysqli_error());

    $d = $con->query("UPDATE login SET kode ='0', aktif='Y' WHERE username='".$username."'") or die (mysqli_error());

    if($d) {
        echo "Selamat! Member dengan username <strong>".$username."</strong> telah aktif";
    } else {
        echo "Gagal diaktifkan";
    }**
```

i try update kode to 0 but the link always enable can disable, can you help me

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider your link be like this

```
<a href="path/to/php">link</a>
```

It is better to use a Session variable in your case.

```
$kode = md5(uniqid(rand()));
$to = $_GET['f11'];
$_SESSION['clicked']=true;
        $headers = "From: rizka.nugroho@omg-indonesia.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-to: $to\r\n";
        $pesan    = "Klik link berikut untuk verifikasi dan mengaktifkan akun : ";
        $pesan    .= ROOT."active.php?email=".$_GET['f11']."&kode=$kode&username=".$_GET['f5'];

        $a = @mail($to, "Aktivasi Akun Anda", $pesan, $headers);
```

In your page where you have the link ,

```
<a <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['clicked']) or $_SESSION['clicked']==false)
echo "href=path/to/php";
else
echo "href='javascript:void(0)'";?> >link</a>
```

Comment: I just suggested an idea. Did you replace href=path/to/php with the links you have been using in your program?